# Javascript - Reduce multidimensional object to string

Tags: javascript, join, data-structures, mapping, reduce

Given object:

```
obj = {
      "zozo": {
          "buys": "6",
          "sells": "9"
      },
      "zaza": {
          "buys": "5",
          "sells": "2"
      }
}
```

How can I reduce this into the string `zozo: buys(6) sells(9), zaza: buys(5) sells(2)` ?

The best I have managed so far is:

```js
obj = {
      "zozo": {
          "buys": "6",
          "sells": "9"
      },
      "zaza": {
          "buys": "5",
          "sells": "2"
      }
}
      
res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((x,y) => `${x}, ${y[0]}: buys(${y[1].buys}) sells(${y[1].sells})`, '');
console.log(res);
```

Which gives me `, zozo: buys(6) sells(9), zaza: buys(5) sells(2)`

I understand this is because I am passing an empty string as initial value, but if I don't do that then the function takes an array as initial value.

Comment: This is expected behavior from the [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) method. What is the actual question?

Comment: You could just append `.substr(2)` at the end ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code by joining the resulting array of strings using [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
const obj = {
  "zozo": {
    "buys": "6",
    "sells": "9"
  },
  "zaza": {
    "buys": "5",
    "sells": "2"
  }
};

const res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((accumulator, [key, value]) => {
  const entry = `${key}: buys(${value.buys}) sells(${value.sells})`;
  return accumulator.concat(entry);
}, []).join(", ");

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you, I was missing the syntax to break the objects down into keys and values.

Answer (score 2):

`reduce` seems overcomplicated, `map()` and `join()` will be enough.

If you let `join()` deal with the `,` between those items, makes it a lot easier

```js
obj = {
      "zozo": {
          "buys": "6",
          "sells": "9"
      },
      "zaza": {
          "buys": "5",
          "sells": "2"
      }
}

const arrayWithStrings = Object.entries(obj).map(x => 
    `${x[0]}: buys(${x[1].buys}) sells(${x[1].sells})`);

const joined = arrayWithStrings.join(',');

console.log(joined)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove first `', '` to get expected value with `.replace(', ','')`.

```js
let obj = {
  "zozo": {
    "buys": "6",
    "sells": "9"
  },
  "zaza": {
    "buys": "5",
    "sells": "2"
  }
};

let res = Object.entries(obj).reduce((x,y) => `${x}, ${y[0]}: buys(${y[1].buys}) sells(${y[1].sells})`, '').replace(', ','');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

A generic approach, which targets the first two levels of any data structure while being agnostic to the keys, based entirely on two nested [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) tasks for both objects levels, the primary outer one and the secondary nested one ...

```js
function customStringifyFirstAndSecondLevel(data) {
  return Object
    .entries(Object(data))
    .map(([primaryKey, primaryValue]) =>
      [
        primaryKey,
        Object
          .entries(primaryValue)
          .map(([secondaryKey, secondaryValue]) =>
            `${ secondaryKey }(${ secondaryValue })`
          )
          .join(' ')
      ]
      .join(': ')
    )
    .join(', ');
}

console.log(
  customStringifyFirstAndSecondLevel({
  "zozo": {
    "buys": "6", "sells": "9",
  },
  "zaza": {
    "buys": "5", "sells": "2",
  },
}));
console.log(
  customStringifyFirstAndSecondLevel({
  foo: {
    buys: 12, sells: 9, keeps: 3,
  },
  bar: {
    buys: 9, keeps: 3, sells: 6,
  },
  baz: {
    buys: 21, sells: 16, keeps: 5,
  },
}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```